# Image Inside Header Causing Header to Expand

Tags: html, css

I'm fairly new to web design, and I've been trying to not have all elements in a page changing position when the window size changes. I was able to do this successfully with everything on the page, with the exception of one image. I wanted this image to stay within the header, but when I made the position relative to the header rather than fixed, it caused the header size to double (even though it's position theoretically shouldn't - from what I can tell of course). When I had used position: fixed before, it looked perfect (except it didn't move with the header upon window changes). I've used Inspect Element to try to identify where the issue was, but I couldn't pinpoint it. Am I missing something important? If more information is needed please let me know! Have a great day!

HTML:

```
<header>
<img src="Images/example.png" alt="Filler">
<h1>Filler Text</h1>
<h6>Filler Text</h6>
<nav role="Navigation">
<div class="container">
  <div><a href="home.html" class="btn">Home</a></div>
  <div><a href="art&vid.html" class="btn">Articles/Videos</a></div>
  <div><a href="mag&pod.html" class="btn">Magazines/Podcasts</a></div>
  <div><a href="cal.html" class="btn">Calendar</a></div>
  <div><a href="about.html" class="btn">About Us</a></div>
</div>
</header>
```

CSS:

```
header {background-color: #ff0000;
        font-family: Georgia;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        margin-top: 10px;
        border-top: 3px solid #000000;
        border-bottom: 3px solid #000000;
        border-left: 3px solid #000000;
        border-right: 3px solid #000000;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 10;
        padding:0;
        position: relative;}

header img {position: relative;
            top: 100px;
            left: 50px;
            max-width:100%;
            max-height:100%;
            border-radius: 10px;}

header h1 {text-align: -webkit-center;}
header h6 {text-align: -webkit-center;}
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me what you're trying to do. However, you're missing a closing tag for `<nav>`.

Answer (score 0):

Does changing your `header img` position to `absolute` fix your issue?

There's a really good article about CSS's `position` property on **A List Apart** [CSS Positioning 101](https://alistapart.com/article/css-positioning-101)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are confused about just a couple of things.

**Positioning** -- When an element has the attribute value `position: fixed;` the browser renders all content as if the fixed element did not exist, then the fixed element is rendered relative to the viewport.

When an element has the attribute value `position: relative;`, the browser leaves space for where that element would have normally been placed (which leaves a blank space and lays out other elements as if it was there), then moves the relative element relative to its normal position.

**Nesting Elements** -- If you don't want an element to break outside its parent container, then generally there is no need to override or declare positioning.

**Display Attributes** -- Every HTML element has a default display value, the most common three you should look at are `block`, `inline`, and `inline-block`.

An image, by default, contains the attribute value `display: inline-block;` which stretches the parent container's width unless the parent container to make room for it unless the parent container's size is declared in the `CSS`, which is why you are seeing the header change sizes.

**Example**

```css
header {
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #f00;
  color: #FFF;
  border: 3px solid #000;
  max-width: 500px;
  padding: 10px;
}

header img {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

h1, h6 {
  text-align: center;
}

.nav {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1000/400/" alt="Filler Photo">
  <h1>Filler Text</h1>
  <h6>Filler Text</h6>
    <ul class="nav">
      <li><a href="/home.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="/art&vid.html">Articles/Videos</a></li>
      <li><a href="/mag&pod.html">Magazines/Podcasts</a></li>
      <li><a href="/cal.html">Calendar</a></li>
      <li><a href="/about.html" class="btn">About Us</a></li>
    </ul>
</header>
```